# lftp + bash script + variables

Tags: linux, variables, queue, mirror, lftp

I'm using lftp to mirror files from external server but now what I need is to after sucessful download rename source directory (on remote server). Basicaly what I need is to open connection on remote server list directories, download all dirs that name starts from "todo" i.e. todo.20121019 after sucess I must rename downloaded directory to "done.20121019". There might be more than one dir on the server.

Remote FTP server works only with active connection.

```
#!/bin/bash

directories=`lftp -f lftp_script_file.lf |grep done|awk '{print $NF}'`

for i in $directories
  do
    echo $i //here I get list of directories that should be downloaded and renamed
  done
```

lftp_script_file.lf just list directires:

```
set ftp:passive-mode false;
open ftp://user:pass$@10.10.10.123
ls my_sub_dir/
```

Is there a way to:

1. open connection to ftp server
2. find directories that I want to download
3. add those dirs to queue and download
4. rename directories on remote server

in batch file?

What I was trying to achive was to list dirs find interesing ones, download and rename but I cant find a way to post list of dirs to lftp via bash script and "set ftp:passive-mode false".

Answer (score 4):

To be able to substitute variables into lftp commands use something like this:

```
lftp -e "cmd1;cmd2"
```